# If $f_n \to f$ is uniformly, does that mean $f$ is continuous?

Tags: analysis

As I was studying uniform continuity, a question hit me:

> If $f_n \to f$ is uniformly, does that mean f is continuous?

I think the answer is no, but i'm not sure. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f_n\to f$ is uniformly continuous"? A sequence of functions and its limit is not uniformly continuous as a whole, only individual functions are uniformly continuous. Do you mean that each of the $f_n$ are uniformly continuous, and that the $f_n$ converge to $f$? Or do you mean that the convergence is uniform? Or maybe that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is equicontinuous, or perhaps even uniformly equicontinuous?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "$f_n \to f$ is uniformly continuous"? Uniform continuity is a property of a single function, not of a sequence of functions. Perhaps you're thinking instead of uniform convergence?

Comment: I can't parse "fn -> f is uniformaly continuous"; did you perhaps mean "if fn => f uniformly"?

Comment: The following facts are true: (i) If $f$ is uniformly continuous, then it is also continuous. (ii) If $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: It might be that you are looking for [uniform equicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity).

Comment: Perhaps you mean "$f_n\to f$ converges uniformly"? And presumably, you want the $f_n$ continuous?

Comment: I meant fn→f uniformly

Answer (score 2):

As Alex said, if the $f_n$ are discontinuous this is false. But, *the uniform limit of  **continuous** functions is continuous.*

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions converging uniformly to $f$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Then, by uniform convergence there exists $N > 0$ such that $$|f(x)-f_n(x)| < \epsilon/3$$ for $n > N.$ By continuity of $f,$ $$|f_N(x)-f_N(y)| < \epsilon/3.$$ By the triangle inequality $$|f(x)-f(y)| < |f(x)-f_N(x)| + |f_N(x)-f_N(y)| + |f(y)-f_N(y)| < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat trivial counterexample:

Let $f$ be some discontinuous function.

Let $f_n = f$ for all $n$.

Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, but by construction, $f$ is not continuous.